# plotting a numpy array : setting axis scale

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I have some troubles trying to keep a well-scaled axis when plotting an image from a numpy array.

Here is my code:

```
def graphique(pixelisation):    
Couleur = {1 : "Vert", 2 : "Orange", 3 : "Rouge"}    
for c in range(1,2):
       liste = np.zeros((int(60//pixelisation),int(150//pixelisation)))
       for d in range(int(150//pixelisation)):
           for v in range(int(60//pixelisation)):
               my_input = {
                   "Distance" : d*pixelisation,
                   "Vitesse" :  v*pixelisation,
                   "Couleur" : c
                           }
               my_output = {
                   "Acceleration" : 0.0
                           }
               liste[v,d] = system.calculate(my_input, my_output).get("Acceleration")
       image = plt.matshow(liste)
       plt.title('a=f(d,v), feu '+Couleur.get(c))
       plt.xlabel('Distance(m)')
       plt.xaxis(0,150)
       plt.xticks(range(0,150,10))
       plt.ylabel('Vitesse(km/h)')
       plt.yticks(range(0,60,10))
       plt.colorbar(image)
       plt.show()    
return liste
```

The problem is that I created a parameter curtailing the size of my array.
But if I divide the size by 2, the x and y axes go from 0 to half normal range.

I made some research in matplotlib database, but found nothing (I actually don't understand all functions).

Thanks for the help !

EDIT :
For example :

`A = np.zeros((10,10))
plt.matshow(A)
plt.show()`

will give me an image with axes going from 0 to 10.

Now if :
`A = np.zeros((100,100))`
And if I want axes to still show a scale from 0 to 10,
how do I do ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the axis scale by calling one of the following functions / methods:

1. With the member functions of the axes object:

   ```
   ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
   ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
   ```

   where `ax` is the axes object (you could get the current one via `ax = plt.gca()` ).
2. With the module function `plt.axis`

   ```
   plt.axis([0, 10, 0, 10])
   ```

You'll find more information in the [documentation of matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html)